# Change Woocommerce Product Title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

If

test.com/shop , title is **Products | ABC**

so

test.com/shop/i_am_a_product , title is **I am a product | ABC**

Now , i want change this Title to **I am a product | ABCDEF** .

How to do ? just add something to title ( Keep index title to ABC ).

Sorry my english , can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I'm assuming that you want to modify the page title in the single product's page. To modify the page title open your theme's `header.php` file.

I'm assuming the current `<title></title>` tag is like following-

```
<title
    <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
    <?php bloginfo('name')?>
</title>
```

Woocommerce provides a function `is_product()` to check that if the current page is the single product page. Use it as following-

```
<title
    <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
    <?php
        if( is_product() ){
            // use your own code here, like ABCDEF
            // this part will only show up in a single product page
        }
        else{
            bloginfo('name'); // this is the name of your website.
            // use your code to display title in all other pages.
        }
</title>
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Thanks.